# Finite Content with Atomfreeness on Infinite Algebra

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, measurable-functions

For an *algebra* $\mathcal{A}$ (not necessarily a $\sigma$-Algebra) over $X =[0,1]$ we define a *finite content* to be a function $\mu \colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0,a]$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ with

1. $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, $\mu(X) = a$ and
2. for all $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$ it holds that $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A \cap B)$.

Furthermore, $\mu$ is said to be *atom-free*, if for all $x \in X$ it holds that $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$.

Obviously, the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is an algebra over $X$. Given these definitions, I am wondering whether there is any formal argument why either

1. there is no finite, atom-free content $\nu \colon \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow [0,1]$ or
2. why one cannot write down such a content $\nu \colon \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow [0,1]$ explicitly in a finite amount of space?

Note that I do not demand $\nu$ to satisfy translation invariance.

Comment: There is a trivial solution with $a = 0$, so I think you mean $\Bbb{R}^{>0}$ not $\Bbb{R}^{\ge 0}$. Also you define the concept *atom-free*, but you don't use it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Indeed, I wanted to ask for a finite, *atom-free* content and edited the question accordingly. Furthermore, I think that $a = 0$ is no trivial solution since I am explicitly asking for a content with $[0,1]$ as image?

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Yes, that was my intention, I clarified the question.

Comment: It is easy to check that Condition 2 in the definition of a finite content is equivalent to the following: for each disjoint $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$ it holds that $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an infinite set $X$, we can pick an arbitrary free ultrafilter $\mathcal F$ on $X$ and define a required content putting for each subset $A$ of $X$ put $\mu(A)=a$, if $A\in\mathcal F$, and $\mu(A)=0$, otherwise.

I think whether the required content can be “constructed” explicitly is a hard question. A similar question for countable $X$ was considered at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95954/how-to-construct-a-continuous-finite-additive-measure-on-the-natural-numbers). According to Stefan Geschke

> In ZF you can't prove that there is a finitely additive measure on $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ (giving all singletons measure 0 and $\mathbb N$ measure 1). The existence of such a measure gives you a subset of $\mathbb R$ without the Baire property, and such a set cannot be constructed without some help of the axiom of choice. In other words, there is no explicit "construction" of a non-trivial finitely additive measure.

I guess the same conclusion holds for your question, but I am to weak in set theory to provide less vague and more rigorous claims.